# FileNotFoundError when I changed directory

Tags: python, directory

I had a working python file with code

```
form_class = uic.loadUiType("PGUI.ui")[0]
```

but I moved both .py file and .ui file to another directory and it doesn't work in VSCode with Error:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'PGUI.ui'

but it work when I make it .exe file with pyinstaller

How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It was my mistake about VSCode usage.

When I open folder A which has A\B\abc.py and A\B\PGUI.ui,

working directory is A, so abc.py cannot refer PGUI.ui